# When I run this code it says "name 'area1' is not defined" can someone explain?

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
import math
radius=float(input("enter a radius value: "))
def area_circumference_generator(radius):
  circumference1=(2*math.pi*radius)
  area1=(math.pi)*(radius**2)
tuple1=(area1,circumference1)
print(tuple1)
```

print("Area of the circle is:",area1)
print("Circumference of the circle is:",circumference1)
area_circumference_generator(radius)

Comment: You need to call the function and then also add a return for `circumference1` and `area1`. Those two variables currently only exist within the function

Answer (score 2):

You can't reference a local variable from outside a function this way. You should first return its value.

```
import math

radius=float(input("enter a radius value: "))

def area_circumference_generator(radius):
  circumference1=(2*math.pi*radius)
  area1 = (math.pi)*(radius**2)
  tuple1 = (area1,circumference1)
  return tuple1 

print(area_circumference_generator(radius))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run it this way:

```
import math


def area_circumference_generator(radius):
    circumference1 = (2*math.pi*radius)
    area1 = (math.pi)*(radius**2)
    tuple1 = (area1, circumference1)
    return tuple1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    radius = float(input("Enter the radius of the circle: "))
    print(area_circumference_generator(radius))
```